# Clear multiple lines

Tags: c, terminal, console, printf

Is it possible to clear multiple lines in C and keep others for example.

Code:

```
Displaysenrsordata
  loop 
    printf("This info stays"); <-stay on screen
    printf("This info stays"); <-stay on screen
    printf("This info Refreshes"); <-update redraw
    printf("This info Refreshes"); <-update redraw
    printf("This info Refreshes"); <-update redraw
```

Essentially I want to have some text to stay at the same place and redraw the updating data without clearing the whole screen.

Comment: You need to specify your environment (Unix terminal/Windows console app/...) as this is beyond ISO C.

Answer (score 6):

If you are working on linux then use [ncurses](http://linux.die.net/man/3/ncurses).

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ncurses.h>
  int main (void)
  {
    int a = 0;
    initscr ();
    printw("This info stays \n");
    printw("This info stays\n");
    curs_set (0);
    while (a < 100) {
            mvprintw (3, 4, "%d", a++);
            mvprintw (3, 8, "%d", a++);
            mvprintw (3, 12, "%d", a++);
            refresh ();
            sleep (1);
    }
    endwin();
    return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can overwrite the current line be printing out a `\r`, or the last character on the current line by printing a `\b`.

Answer (score -5):

No, you can't clear only a part of the console window.

Comment: You can't even clear the full screen in standard C++.

Comment: @BenjaminBannier Not part of the standard, but you can do system("cls") or system("clear") which works fine if refresh rate isn't too high.